# Google-API AndroidPublisher error: reviewQueryQuotaExceeded

Tags: google-api, google-play

I'm making a call to the Google AndroidPublisher API to post developer responses to GooglePlay reviews, and the api is giving me the reviewQueryQuotaExceeded error and I do not understand why, because I theoretically have 500 calls per day, and the new day has just started .

I need to know what this error might mean and how I could find out more information about the error. I'm using the .Net Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2.dll library.

Thank you very much to all.

This is the complete error message:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Review query quota exceeded. [403]
Errors [
Message[Review query quota exceeded.] Location[ - ] 
Reason[reviewQueryQuotaExceeded] Domain[androidpublisher]
]
```

Comment: Wait until midnight west cost USA time if it works then you know you are hitting the quota.    How many requests have you sent?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but it is 1 o'clock in the night on the west coast of the USA and I still have quota exceeded, as for the number of requests, I'm doing about 20 every 6 and a half minutes, because they are the number of answers I have yet to answer, however if at some point I had had a quota, the number of pending answers would have decreased and yet it has not decreased. Thank you

Comment: What makes you say you have 500 calls per day?  I think you should check Google Play Console You are hitting a quota limit.  The error message doesn't lie and if you it it after midnight today your going to have to wait until tomorrow to try again.

Comment: Hi again, I waited until midnight and I still have the same error message, do you know if there is any way to visualize the number of calls that have been made to the api from the specific account?

And some way to check if the account has been disallowed?

Thank you

Comment: You can check the Google Developer console it should show activity of your project.